# I have a two-dimensional table, how can I bring the data as follows?

Tags: php, mysql

Table name `client`

```
id name        mail
1  semsi pasa  semsi@semsi.com
2  demir ali    mermer@mermer.com
```

Table name `registerid`

```
fields clientid values
4       1        94858
5       1        3493848484
4       2        32423
5       2        4324242342
```

---

```
foreach($user as $key => $val){
  echo "one row:".$user[$key]['name']." ".$user[$key]['mail']." ".$user[$key]['values']."<br>";
}
```

It will look like on screen

```
semsi pasa semsi@semsi.com 948583493848484
demir ali  mermer@mermer.com 324234324242342
```

Comment: A simple ’JOIN’ in your SQL is needed to combine the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tt.value order by tt.fieldid = 4 separator '' ) FROM tc JOIN tt ON tc.id = tt.relid where tt.fieldid IN ('4','5') group by tc.id
```

Thanks in the way I did it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for aggregation:

```
select c.name, c.mail, group_concat(r.values order by fields separator '' )
from client c join
     registerid r
     on c.id = r.clientid
group by c.id;
```

Note:  If you decide you want a separate between the values, then use something besides `''`.

Comment: I want the fields values 5 and 4 to come up with those.

Answer (score 0):

as  you need to get fields values also,

so adding "fields" on above answer, you get this query-

```
select c.name, c.mail, r.fields, group_concat(r.values order by fields separator '' )
from client c join
     registerid r
     on c.id = r.clientid
group by c.id;
```